# How to manually run application as "IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool" user

Tags: iis, iis-7, runas

I tried:

```
runas /noprofile /user:"IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool" cmd.exe
```

But it asks me for a password. My admin password does not work there.

I get:

> RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that. `IIS AppPool\<user>` accounts are "Application Pool Identity" accounts which are synthesised by IIS when the pool is running. `ApplicationPoolIdentity` account lifetimes are managed entirely by IIS and the OS and you'll never be able to authenticate interactively with them.

Comment: Actually I have workaround.
I can create new WebApplication and link it to that AppPool
And then from that application do
`Process.Start("cmd.exe");`
But it is too complicated and I thought that something simpler should be available.

Comment: No other ideas?